# Visual Studio Intellisense not up to date for one class

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

For some reasons Intellisense is not up to date for 1 class (C++) in my project (when I call a method it refers to the old parameters and so on)!

I'm able to compile but it would be fine if there is an option to update Intellesense (refresh local cache or something)?

Thx

Comment: Which language are you using? The intellisense systems are quite different across them.

Comment: Under the `Project Menu` there should be a `Rescan Solution` option. Does that correct your IntelliSense problem?

Comment: I don't have this option in Visual Studio 2008 Project menu! Where can I find this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unload the project in the solution and reload it!
(now I solved this issue)

Answer (score 0):

I helped myself by renaming the intellisense database file (*.ncb) to - as example - *.ncbx. This helped me for my VS2008 Problem. But first you have to leave the IDE to relase the file. When starting the IDE again, the *.ncb File will be recreated - now with the actual parameters.

Hope that helps some more developers, too.