# MS Visual Studio doesent give a hints

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and intellisense is not working.

For example from the below code when i try to access methods inside `e` it doesn't prompting me the available methods.

```
private: System::Void textBox1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e){
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the intellisense cache? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct that sadly Intellisense is gone for C++/CLI in VS 2010.  It's back in VS 2012 and for VS 2010, I recommend [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com) if you can afford it.

Comment: VisualAssist is excellent. If you can afford to get it you should - if for no other reason to support the folks at WholeTomato.

Answer (score 0):

I found VS 2010 is not supporting intellisense for C++/CLI. Guess theres no way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 has Intellisense again. There is a [express (free) desktop development version that supports c++. Here is an explanation](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-editions) as to why not then and why now.