# Xamarin razor template inherit breaks Intellisense in editor

Tags: razor, xamarin, mono, android-webview, razorgenerator

When using @inherits in a razor template view in portable library for a Xamarin-based hybrid app, the intellisense is broken such that it red-underlines the functions provided by the base view class such as "@Model".  I have a fresh update of the Xamarin tools (4.1.0.530).

The first fix here doesn't apply: [Xamarin WebView - No Intellisense in razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952666/xamarin-webview-no-intellisense-in-razor)

I'm not sure if this is related, but the RazorTemplateProcessor doesn't seem to be reading my web.config such that I also have to reference class names fully qualified, or the generated code-behind file will have a compile error.  How to get it to support web.config?

Comment: I have the same Problem. No one is answering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103385/fresh-xamarin-webview-razor-template-intellisense-errors