# Xamarin Razor WebView Template missing reference

Tags: android, xamarin, razor, webview, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed VS2017. I cannot get Intellisense to work in a fresh WebViewApp (Android).

[image]
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GABoJjSQOA

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot get Intellisense to work in a fresh WebViewApp (Android).

You could double-check if the following steps change the behavior :

- Close all open tabs in the project.
- Quit Visual Studio.
- Reopen the solution in Visual Studio.
- Right-click the XAML file (in your case is `RazorView.cshtml`) in the Solution Explorer and then select `Open With...` > `Source Code (Text) Editor` as before.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did all four steps you provided. Intellisense indeed does not throw these errors anymore, it still does not work either. Cannot really be a solution to turn off Intellisense completely by opening a different text editor. For more details please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535174/intellisense-errors-in-xamarin-webview-project