# Intellisense errors in Xamarin WebView Project

Tags: android, xamarin, razor, webview, visual-studio-2017

Intellisense does not work in Razor Files (.cshtml) in a Xamarin Mono.Android Project (e.g. your [RazorTodo](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/) or in `VS2017: New Project -> Choose Visual C# -> WebView-App (Android)`)

Compilation is fine, but I am getting reference errors (Intellisense only).

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' 
The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
```

There is no `System.Web.dll` in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\

**I just wanted to know if this is expected behavior?**

I will provide further Screenshots or info if required. Thank you for your support.

---

In addition I cannot compile the project. There are errors in the processed file (.cs) of my Razor view (.cshtml).

```
Name "Href" is not found in current context
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When you are referencing libraries in `.cshtml pages` make sure that you are adding `'@'` before you reference the library.

-Example:

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Web;
```