# Razor template In xamarin

Tags: html, xamarin, razor, xamarin.forms

I would like to use razor template I use vs19 on windows
no option for creating a new

> RazorTemplatePreprocessor

so, in the shared project I created an empty text file and change extension to .cshtml and change file custom tool from property to

> RazorTemplatePreprocessor

which generated the corresponding cs file

in cshtml file

```
@using DataBase.Models;

@model List<Brand>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            @foreach (var m in Model)
            {
                <div class="one-fifth column">
                    <span class="d-inline-block p-3 bg-red text-white">
                        @m.ModelName
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="four-fifths column">
                    <span class="d-inline-block p-3 bg-green">
                        @m.ModelDescription
                    </span>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in loop there are an error for Model (var m in **Model**)

> The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Try to change (It's better to pass your Model class)

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
```

to

```
@foreach (var m in @Model)
```

The `@model` directive should be followed by a `Type`,this could be any custom class.

When `@Model` is referenced throughout the template, it provides a reference to the object passed to the template when it is generated.

**Update**:

for example,your model class like:

```
public class YourModel{
    ...

    public List<Brand> Brands{ get; set; }

    public class Brand{
       public strin  ModelName{ get; set; }
       public strin  ModelDescription{ get; set; }
    }
 }
```

then

```
@using DataBase.Models;

@model YourModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            @foreach (var m in @Model.Brands)
            {
                <div class="one-fifth column">
                    <span class="d-inline-block p-3 bg-red text-white">
                        @m.ModelName
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="four-fifths column">
                    <span class="d-inline-block p-3 bg-green">
                        @m.ModelDescription
                    </span>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it before but the same message

Comment: @SherifAwad You could try  referencing your model class instead of `List<Brand>` like above.

Comment: I did but the same error even I tried a new project

Comment: The error is gone after following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508002/xamarin-razor-webview-template-missing-reference/46556217#46556217