# can't access model or any intellisense in views of mvc 5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

My project was running fine then something happened and views of mvc 5 turned into simple text. I'm using Visual studio 2015 and my project is in MVC 5. CourseRegistration is my Model It was working before then my VS crashed and now my views are like plain text except for the html tags. [See Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxG6.jpg)

Comment: [Here check all responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309817/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-not-work)

Comment: I've already applied all these steps, but none of them worked. plus the project runs fine on one of my friend's laptop.