# How to fix The name "ViewBag" doesn't exist in file javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a issue in Visual Studio 2017. I want to get data from the controller in the Razor file. So the value doesn't exist in the file.

The code and problem is below.

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Product(int? product)
{
    if (product == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.product = product;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**scripts:**

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var pr = @ViewBag.product;
    </script>
}
```

Error:
[image]

Some links of what I haved tried in order to fix it:
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309817/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-stopped-working)
[question2](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-fix-broken-intellisense-in-visual-studio-razor-views/)

Comment: What is the **exact name** of the scripts file?

Comment: The expectation is that you will respond to comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, make sure that value is set in ViewBag.product in controller.

Answer (score 2):

Place value in quotes:

```
var pr = '@ViewBag.product';
```

Comment: I tried it so result is " var pr =' '   " showing in script when i run . The name @ViewBag doen't even exist .

Comment: @vankhanhpr so, your `@ViewBag.product` is null or empty

Comment: It's empty like the picture above.Thanks!