# VS 2019 Intellisense Suddenly Quit Working in View/Razor Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense

I have been working on this project for a couple months and suddenly intellisense quit working only in the view/cshtml files. I had left VS open and debugging for several days without working on the project. When I came back I didn't have any color coding for the C# parts of the files. I also found that it doesn't work in any of the views, but does work in my controllers and models. I have tried many suggestions, but to no luck. I tried everything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309817/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-stopped-working) link.

I am working on a basic MVC app in VS2019. I have Bootstrap 3, Jquery, and Entity Framework installed.

I would greatly appreciate any help. This is driving me nuts.

Update: This is also not working in any solutions in Visual Studio. So maybe something wrong in VS?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528369/16399561)?

Comment: @osfresia My web.configs already looked like that. I started this as an MVC3 project in VS2019. I was not going through any updates, as I started the project in the current version.

Comment: I meant MVC 5 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed after installing Visual Studio 2022 and opening the project there. Still in the dark as to what caused the problem in VS2019.