# Intellisense no longer highlighting type specifiers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2012 all the type specifiers in my cpp files are no longer being highlighted.  Not all my cpp files are affected, but each day a few more are.

I have followed all the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken) stackoverflow post.  The only thing that worked is ColinBurke's suggestion.

> selecting the end of the very last line of the file, and then saving
>   the file (ctrl-s) fixes the problem.

However, this is just a workaround.  If I do not save this way each time while working with an affected file all the type specifier highlights disappear.

Has anyone had a similar experience and have a solution?