# Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense & Highlighting stopped working for ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App after installing Xamarin Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, installation, intellisense, xamarin-studio

After installing **Xamarin Studio** **Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense & Highlighting** stopped working for **ASP.NET MVC 5 Web App**.

Syntax and IntelliSense for my **MVC 4 Web Projects** are there when I open or create a new MVC 4 Web  project.
**Syntax and IntelliSense** for my **MVC 5 Web Projects** are gone and I believe it happened right after I installed Xamarin Studio which has a few SDKs and some other stuff that integrates into Visual Studio.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

PS: I just created a New **MVC 4** and **MVC 5** projects and looking for what could be causing the issue - because **MVC 4** project's **IntelliSense & Highlighting** is there and **MVC 5**'s is not.

Here is a Web.Config file for MVC 5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is a packages.config file for MVC 5

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: You could try uninstalling and reinstalling - [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)?

Comment: I re-installed it but with no luck. The thing is intellisense works in libraries - controllers but it does not in the View. Thank for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking for an answer I have seen some folks struggling with the same issue after installing `Xamarin Studio`.

I finally was able to fix it by installing `Microsoft ASP.NET Razor Version 2.1.0` 
Now Intellisense is working on the View as well.

I wish I could also leave a comment on [some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken) (I don't have enough reputation to do so) because it looks like they are struggling with the same `MVC 5` Intellisense issue (one guy there reported that it started happening after Xamarin installation as well)and that solution could possibly help them.

Comment: I upvoted question and answer so maybe you can comment & answer there now?

Comment: I put it on my note list - so whenever I get those 50 points - I will go there and add a comment. Thank you very much though!