# How can I stop Visual Studio 2013 from unfocusing the editor when writing setters in XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop.

When working with WPF and editing XAML, the editor has this really annoying habit of freezing for a second and unfocusing the editor when writing a setter in a style.

For example: if I start writing a style like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property=
</Style>
```

As soon as I type the `"` after `Property=`, Visual Studio freezes for a second, the Design view crashes and displays `An Unhandled Exception has occured`, and keyboard focus switches from the editor to another window in Visual Studio causing me to have to click back in the editor window to continue typing the setter.

This will happen anytime the design view ISN'T crashed.

How can I stop Visual Studio from freezing and losing focus on the editor?

Comment: Maybe the steps here for clearing intellisense cache will work for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Comment: Didn't fix the problem but I did find something out.  After resetting my visual studio settings, "Auto insert attribute quotes" was enabled which means when entering a property it'll auto insert both quotes automatically and the problem doesn't occur.  It seems when typing the first quote only, Visual Studio tries parsing the rest of the XAML as an attribute and failing.  I'm so used to typing my quotes manually though :(  Man this is annoying...