# Trouble moving C++ solution from VS2013 Ultimate to Pro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I've been developing a C++ program on my desktop, but want to move to my laptop.  Desktop runs VS2013 Ultimate, laptop runs Pro (employer's licensing issues).

When I do, I get the following:

```
12  IntelliSense: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "bsearch_s" (declared at line 439)    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h 588 33  MyProgram
13  IntelliSense: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "bsearch" (declared at line 443)  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h 591 33  MyProgram
14  IntelliSense: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "qsort_s" (declared at line 448)  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h 595 16  MyProgram
15  IntelliSense: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "qsort" (declared at line 452)    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdlib.h 599 16  MyProgram
16  IntelliSense: a function type involving a generic parameter cannot have an ellipsis parameter   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vadefs.h 83  21  MyProgram
17  IntelliSense: a function type involving a generic parameter cannot have an ellipsis parameter   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vadefs.h 84  23  MyProgram
```

Anyone have any idea what the problem is? I'm concerned because (a) I want to move development to my laptop, but (b) because I want to be able to come back and compile this in the future, at which point I'm sure my IDE will have changed again.  Are there really not enough details in the .sln files to move from Ultimate to Pro without errors?!

**Edit:**  I have tried the following:

- Installed updates for VS2013 Pro (Update 5)
- Closed VS, deleted .suo file
- Reset settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings )

Comment: Probably something silly as missing a service pack. Note that they're Intellisense warnings. Intellisense caches compilation results, and that cache might now be invalid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Comment: Thanks, I did try all the solutions in that thread (except resetting cache & deleting the v12.0\ReflectedSchemas, since neither exist in VS2013), with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an "Answer" in case anyone comes across this...

Since it compiles, I just disabled the Intellisense errors and ignored the issue.  Not perfect, but it works.