# After dot tip shows only for very short time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In visual studio ASP.NET MVC  in Views  when I write for example

@Html.

after dot tip shows only for very short time and then disappears.
Why is that?

Comment: Reboot? That sometimes happens to me. Ctrl+space should also open intelisense.

Comment: this should help. this one is for VS 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Comment: Only in HTML but Ctrl+space helped, thanks.