# ASP script src 'file was not found'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hello stackoverflowers,

I have a small issue when i try to use a .js file in a ascx page.

```
<script src="~/foo.js"></script>
```

After the `/`, Visual Studio auto-completion propose me to select foo.js among other elements in the folder, but then i got the "File ~/foo.js was not found" error.

Any idea about the cause of this issue ?

Comment: Try the answer given here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375961/visual-studio-2012-intellisense-sometimes-disappearing-broken

Comment: I hoped so much, it took a few seconds for intellisense to kick in and mark the file as not found again

Comment: Did you delete the `.suo` file in the project folder?